What counts as a canonical isomorphism from $V\otimes W$?
Up until now I had understood a canonical isomorphism as one that can be expressed without mention to the bases of the vector spaces in questions, and would only use the 'defining properties' of a vector space.
However, what happens if the vector spaces in questions are defined by means of their bases. Consider, for instance, the tensor product $V\otimes W$ defined from some bases of $V$ and $W$. What could possibly count as a canonical isomorphism $V\otimes W\to X$?

Context: my question came up when reading the Wikipedia article on the tensor product, where two equivalent characterizations of $V\otimes W = \{v\otimes w : v\in B_V,w\in B_w\}$ for bases $B_V$ and $B_W$ of $V$ and $W$ respectively are given:

$V\otimes W$ is the vector space that has the elements $\{v\otimes w : v\in B_V,w\in B_W\}$ as a basis, or

$V\otimes W$ is the vector space of bilinear forms $V\times W\to F$ that are zero at all but finitely many of the elements of $B_V\times B_W$.


In my understanding these two definitions are equivalent due to the isomorphism $\phi:V\otimes W\to (V\times W)^*$ defined by
$$(v\otimes w)(x,y)
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } (x,y)=(v,w),\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
for $v\in B_V,w\in B_W$. A natural question to make is whether this isomorphism is canonical, at which point I realized that, because $V\otimes W$ is itself defined by making a choice of bases for $V$ and $W$ (and finally for $V\otimes W$ itself), any isomorphism from $V\otimes W$ will have to reference such basis, and thus -it seems- cannot be canonical.

Well, maybe not any isomorphism needs to reference a basis of $V\otimes W$. Think of $x\mapsto 2x$. However, any isomorphism that uses the definition of $V\otimes W$ will necessarily reference a basis of $V\otimes W$, as the vector space is defined in terms of one of its bases.

Your wikipedia link gives two more equivalent definitions of the tensor product, which are basis-free: as a quotient space and via its universal property. Especially the latter is what I'd first think of when considering "canonical" or "natural" maps.

$(V \times W)^*$ usually denotes the dual space of $V \times W$. This is not the same as than the vector space of bilinear forms $V\times W\to F$ that are zero at all but finitely many of the elements of $B_V\times B_W$.

What do you expect as canonical isomorphisms? Without knowing any structure, you only get things like $V\otimes W\to W\otimes V$ or to $Hom(V^,W)$ or to $(V^\otimes W^)^$. The latter two with dual vector spaces only work without restriction in finite dimension.

There are basis-free constructions of the tensor product.
The common one (which also appears on wikipedia) is to take the quotient of the space of formal linear combinations $\sum_k \alpha_k \cdot v_k \underline{\otimes} w_k$ (where $v_k \in V$, $w_k \in W$) modulo the subspace $R$ spanned by elements of the form $$(\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2) \underline{\otimes} w - \alpha_1 \cdot v_1 \underline{\otimes} w - \alpha_2 \cdot v_2 \underline{\otimes} w,$$ $$v \underline{\otimes} (\beta_1 w_1 + \beta_2 w_2) - \beta_1 \cdot v \underline{\otimes} w_1 - \beta_2 \cdot v \underline{\otimes} w_2,$$
forcing bilinearity of the operation $\otimes$ defined as $v \otimes w = v \underline{\otimes} w + R$.
This is not a very good definition to work with directly, but to construct maps from the tensor product space we use the universal property of tensor product: for every bilinear map $\beta \colon V \times W \to X$ there is a unique linear map $B\colon V \otimes W \to X$ such that $B(x \otimes y) = \beta(x, y)$. Of course it then follows that $$B(\sum_{k} \alpha_k \cdot v_k \otimes w_k) = \sum_{k} \alpha_k \beta(v_k, w_k),$$
and the universal property guarantees that the right hand side here does not depend on the specific decomposition $\alpha_k \cdot v_k \otimes w_k$, only on the resulting tensor.
Sometimes it is convenient to use the universal property implicitly, saying something like "Consider the linear map $B\colon V \otimes W \to X$ defined on elementary tensors as $B(v \otimes w) = $ (some bilinear expression in $v$ and $w$)"
For example, we can define a linear map $S \colon V \otimes W \to W \otimes V$ such that $S(v \otimes w) = w \otimes v$, or a linear map $T \colon V \otimes V^* \to F$ such that $T(v \otimes f) = f(v)$. I would say $S$ is a canonical isomorphism.


what happens if the vector spaces in questions are defined by means of their bases. Consider, for instance, the tensor product $V \otimes W$ defined from some bases of $V$ and $W$.

That is simply working with a "bad" definition of tensor products.  It is like defining real numbers as infinite decimal expansions: it can be used for computational purposes, and for physicists or engineers it may be good enough in certain settings, but ultimately it is a poor way to think about tensor products and what their role is.  In particular, tensor products can be constructed is settings other than vector spaces, namely for modules, where there may not be a basis at all.
An example of a canonical isomorphism involving $V \otimes W$ is the "swap" isomorphism $V \otimes W \to W \otimes V$ where $v \otimes w \mapsto w \otimes v$ on all elementary tensors. There is at most one linear mapping $V \otimes W \to W \otimes V$ with the indicated effect on all elementary tensors since the elementary tensors span $V \otimes W$, but to show there really is such a linear mapping needs a better way to conceptualize $V \otimes W$ than the way you're thinking about it using a basis.
If you insist on using bases, then at least show your description is independent of the choice of basis, because when a construction uses a basis but turns out to lead to the same result no matter what basis is used, this means the construction is independent of the choice of basis and thus it does not depend on bases.
